Open subset of paracompact manifold is paracompact?
I assume a smooth manifold is paracompact (including Hausdorff) instead of Hausdorff and second countable. We can show that a connected topological manifold is paracompact iff it's second countable. We also know that since a manifold is locally connected, it can be written as the disjoint union of its connected components.
I know a subspace of second-countable space is second countable, but not all open subspace of paracompact space is paracompact. Also, open subspace of second-countable smooth manifold is a smooth manifold.

Is an open subspace of a paracompact smooth manifold always a paracompact smooth manifold? In particular it is sufficient to show (or provide a counterexample) that an open subset of a paracompact manifold is paracompact

I think the open subspace is the disjoint union of connected components, where each of the connected components is second-countable, as a subspace of second countable space. We also have the disjoint union of second countable manifold as a manifold (in the topological sense). Then using the theorem that a connected topological manifold is paracompact iff it's second countable. Then we have the open subspace in paracompact.
Does this proof sketch work?

Well, you can prove more:
Let $X$ be a paracompact $T_2$ manifold.
Since $X$ is locally compact, it is regular.
As mentioned in the question, local connectness implies that each component is clopen, hence a connected, paracompact $T_2$ manifold, hence second countable, hence metrizable.
Thus, $X$ is the sum of metrizable spaces, and therefore metrizable. Of course, each subset is then paracompact.

Sorry for the typo. Thank you. I see, so every paracompact manifold is the disjoint union of metrizable space thus also metrizable.
